# Looking for reference for Apples A5 cache size

Tags: ipad, ios

I saw http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_A5 where they tell that the L2 in Apple A5 is 1MB, however, I could not find any official reference or white paper or research publication of it, even though I searched both Google and Google Scholar.

Would you kindly give an idea of or pointer on how can I search for that. I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: What would you consider 'official'? Did you go through all the references in the cited article already?

Comment: Thanks. I mean, any publication/report etc., which I can cite. The references therein are mostly website articles by technical-news-agencies and discuss more 'personal opinions' of journalists and facts based on unofficial released info.

Comment: With the A5 being a proprietary chip you may be hard pressed to find a source like that.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I could find the reference for A4, though. It was "The AppleTV-Cluster: Towards Energy Efficient Parallel Computing on Consumer Electronic Devices".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detailed specs on Apple's processors for iOS devices are usually not mentioned. Mosty likely as Apple's focus is on a product's performance *as a whole*. Mere numbers for memory, cache and clocks don't reflect that.

Therefore, even a professional blog such as [AnandTech](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4215/apple-ipad-2-benchmarked-dualcore-cortex-a9-powervr-sgx-543mp2/2) draws such information from running a [GeekBench](http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/geekbench-2/id377657310?mt=8) test:

**L2 Cache is 1MB and shared among both cores.**

But note that these are not official numbers confirmed by Apple.

[image]

<sub>[[picture from AnandTech](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4215/apple-ipad-2-benchmarked-dualcore-cortex-a9-powervr-sgx-543mp2/2)]</sub>

Comment: How did you see 2MB total, since it says, "L2 cache size has also apparently increased from 512KB to 1MB. The L2 cache is shared among both cores and 1MB seems to be the sweet spot this generation.". Would you please tell me.

Comment: @user984260 Of course you're right. Don't know how I doubled that in my head... :)